# How to delete all of a users files (and a user in general )in firebase.storage?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire

Have an app that I want to be able to delete users. I can delete everything in the database. But firebase storage I am unable to delete the user and their files that they uploaded.

**I am able to delete an individual file** (file location/reference) for example with

```
const userStorageRef = this.storage.ref(`/${deletedUid}/full/TimeStamp/fileName.png`);
return userStorageRef.delete();
```

But unable to delete all files at once or user from storage with api.
**Getting error** Firebase Storage Error Object reference does not exist

My FIREBASE DATA STRUCTURE is like this(the root is not angular-app but same structure)

**gs://angular-app.appspot.com/userId/fullImages/[list of fileKeys]/imageFile[.png, jpeg, gif]**

Using Angularfire2(v5) but to delete the storage, really just accessing the normal webapi for firebase storage.

Using typscript so constructor looks like

```
constructor(private app: FirebaseApp) {
    // Regular firebase api
    this.fbDatabase = this.app.database();
    this.storage = this.app.storage();
}


deleteUsersStorage(deletedUid) {
    // Tried also .ref(`/${deletedUid}/`)
    // .ref(`/${deletedUid}`)
    // .ref(`${deletedUid}/`)
    // .ref().child(`${deletedUid}`)    and more
    const userStorageRef = this.storage.ref(`${deletedUid}`);
    userStorageRef.delete()
        .then((r) => { 
            console.log('Deletion success');
         })
         .catch((e) => { 
             console.log('Error in storage deletion: ',  e);
         });
}
```

Getting error 
Firebase Storage Error Object reference does not exist

**My FIREBASE DATA STRUCTURE** is like this(the root is not angular-app but same structure)

gs://angular-app.appspot.com/userId/fullImages/[list of fileKeys]/imageFile[.png, jpeg, gif]

The brackets are meant to reference what is there ie. list of fileKeys is a description of the location

**update** 
my instinct now answer may be in the storage rules. Will need to work it later.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/angular-app.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is fullRef?

Comment: updated the code - that was a error. It slightly shortened code from the actual and forgot to clean up that part